# Clean way to perform commands in the Emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

Consider the following example: I want to read a file using ido from the minibuffer, but merge in all of the directories I use often. I can't just execute

```
(ido-find-file)
(ido-merge-work-directories)
```

Because the second sexp will only execute after the user is finished selecting the file. The question then is: what is the best/cleanest way to execute commands in the minibuffer's command loop?

The only way I know to do this is to bind my desired command to a key sequence, and add that sequence to unread-command-events so the key runs once we enter the minibuffer command loop:

```
(setq unread-command-events (append (listify-key-sequence (kbd "M-s")) unread-command-events)) ; std key-binding for ido-merge-work-directories
(ido-find-file)
```

But that is very hacky, and I would like to know if there is a better solution.

Thanks!

**Edit:** just to clarify, this question is NOT about ido. Let me explain. When you call a function such as find-file, or switch-to-buffer, or anything that requires minibuffer interaction, a "recursive edit" is created--that is, a command loop inside of a command loop.

So, the code:

```
(message "A")
(recursive-edit) 
(message "B")
```

prints A, then suspends the execution of the function and reenters the command loop. You can move around, open files, etc, until you leave the recursive edit, and then "B" is printed.

So, let me rephrase my question: if you create a recursive edit, how do you then execute a command (in the same function) in the new command loop that was created? It doesn't count if I have to type extra keys. For the ido example, to merge the directories, ido must be running: executing the merge directories before ido is called isn't inside ido's command loop. If you execute it afterwards, then ido destroys its command loop.

Comment: Do you *always* want to merge the additional directories?

Comment: It's just an example, but for the application I am writing (project management lib) the answer is yes. I am primarily interested in the answer to the general question: if I enter the minibuffer command loop, how do I cleanly execute commands in that loop?

Answer (score 1):

So I think there are three answers to your question:

- You can bind keys in the minibuffer map, just the same as any other. There are [several keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Maps.html) that are potentially relevant.
- `ido` has a number of hooks available to change the behavior of various functions, in particular the `ido-make-*-hook` variables seem relevant. (If you've never used it, `M-x describe-variable`, aka `\C-h v`, is your friend.)
- If you want to universally change the behavior of a function and there's no hook available, you should consider `defadvice`. In your case, I think you'd be good to go with (untested!):

  ```
  (defadvice ido-find-file (before)
     (ido-merge-work-directories))
  (ad-activate ido-find-file)
  ```

  You can add these lines to your `.emacs`:

  ```
  (when (require 'ido)
    (defadvice ido-find-file (before)
       (ido-merge-work-directories))
    (ad-activate ido-find-file))
  ```

Comment: None of these work. Of course I can bind keys in the minibuffer map, but I don't want the user to have to type more. ido has hooks, but none that I have seen that allow you to execute arbitrary code in its loop, furthermore the question isn't specifically about ido. advice won't work either, if you advise before then the code gets executed before ido creates its command loop... if you do it after, then the command executes when ido has already closed its command loop.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the manual:

> In general, we try to minimize the use of recursive editing levels in
>   GNU Emacs.  This is because they constrain you to "go back" in a
>   particular order--from the innermost level toward the top level.  When
>   possible, we present different activities in separate buffers so that
>   you can switch between them as you please.  Some commands switch to a
>   new major mode which provides a command to switch back.  These
>   approaches give you more flexibility to go back to unfinished tasks in
>   the order you choose.

So can you describe the scenario you actually need to do this?  Ido is very
weird for working the way it does in this case.

Comment: I know they are "frowned upon", but every minibuffer operation invokes a recursive edit, so it isn't exactly a rare case. The example in my post is the one that prompted me to post this question, but I've also needed it in the past to inject minibuffer input into third party libs that provided crappy APIs. I'm not interested in "different ways to solve a practical problem I am having ATM"; I already found a working hack. I purely want to know if there is a clean way to perform commands in inner recursive edit command loops, if there isn't a clean way I'll just hack up a patch at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me just what you are asking, but it sounds a bit like you are asking how to invoke a command interactively that reads from the minibuffer when you are not at top-level.

If that is the question then the answer is simple: bind `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to non-`nil` around the command invocation.